# SQL Server column containing XML needs to be concatentated

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xslt

I have a sql server 2008 r2 database that contains a table with raw XML in one of the columns. I have written a query to extract data from this table using group by and stuff to concatenate all of the columns that meet a 2 column group by clause. The issue is that when I stuff the columns I get duplicate XML declarations and the XML is not valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fruits>
    <Fruit Type="Lemons" Price="0.50" />
    <Fruit Type="Apples" Price="0.75" />
</Fruits>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fruits>
    <Fruit Type="Cherries" Price="0.10" />
    <Fruit Type="Dates" Price="0.25" />
</Fruits>
```

I looked at adding a substring call to remove this declaration but the query is getting quite complex and slow. I am working with an XSLT transformer that creates XML output. In the end I have many rows that can be delivered to a common destination. I basically need a way to concatenate the XML while removing the duplicate XML declarations and handling the XML hierarchy

This would be converted to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fruits>
    <Fruit Type="Lemons" Price="0.50" />
    <Fruit Type="Apples" Price="0.75" />
    <Fruit Type="Cherries" Price="0.10" />
    <Fruit Type="Dates" Price="0.25" />
</Fruits>
```

Does anyone know how to do this in a systematic way? I am not actually working with fruit but used it as a simplified example.

Here is the actual query

```
SELECT tt.ProductCodeID, tt.ProviderID, tt.ContentXML, LEN(tt.ContentXML) AS xmllength     from

(SELECT p.ProductCodeID, l.ProviderID, 

 STUFF((
SELECT pl1.Content FROM dbo.Payload pl1 
INNER JOIN Log l1 ON pl1.LogID=l1.LogID
INNER JOIN Provider p1 ON l1.ProviderID=p1.ProviderID

WHERE pl1.ProductCodeID=p.ProductCodeID  AND     

pl1.PayloadTypeID=pt.PayloadTypeID       
AND p1.ProviderID=l.ProviderID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS ContentXML

FROM dbo.Queue q 
INNER JOIN log l ON q.LogID=l.LogID
INNER JOIN payload pl ON l.LogID=pl.LogID
INNER JOIN dbo.PayloadType pt ON pl.PayloadTypeID = pt.PayloadTypeID
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCode p ON pl.ProductCodeID= p.ProductCodeID
INNER JOIN dbo.Status s ON q.StatusID=s.StatusID 
WHERE s.Name = 'processed' AND pt.Name='MIF'
GROUP BY  p.ProductCodeID, l.ProviderID, pt.PayloadTypeID) AS tt
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly, but if you always know what the objects are going to be you could strip out the xml you don't want.

```
SELECT ..., '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Fruits>' + 
            REPLACE( REPLACE(xml_column, 
                             '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Fruits>', 
                             ''), 
                     '</Fruits', 
                     '') + 
            '</Fruits>
```

Or, use a similar step to preprocess the data, and use the replace function to add a column missing the xml headers.

Comment: I started down this pathway but worry that changes in schema would require recoding. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: In the end I think this is the best solution. I am really surprised that SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't have the ability to apply XPath expressions to columns. Thanks again for you suggestion.

Comment: good luck with it! I'd appreciate the 'accept' if it was useful. As an aside, probably the better answer would be to parse the XML in to structured tables before it goes in to the table, but that seemed out of scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the quick solution that I can think of right now.

```
CREATE TABLE Test2(ID INT,Col1 XML, Col2 XML)
INSERT INTO Test2 VALUES(1,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Fruits><Fruit Type="Lemons" Price="0.10" /><Fruit Type="Apples" Price="0.25" /></Fruits>','<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Fruits><Fruit Type="Cherries" Price="0.10" /><Fruit Type="Dates" Price="0.25" /></Fruits>')
INSERT INTO Test2 VALUES(2,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Fruits><Fruit Type="Lemons2" Price="0.10" /><Fruit Type="Apples2" Price="0.25" /></Fruits>','<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Fruits><Fruit Type="Cherries2" Price="0.10" /><Fruit Type="Dates3" Price="0.25" /></Fruits>')

SELECT ID, (
SELECT Fruit,Price FROM(
SELECT  
       Tbl.Col.value('@Type', 'varchar(100)') AS Fruit,  
       Tbl.Col.value('@Price', 'varchar(10)') AS Price
FROM   Col1.nodes('//Fruit') Tbl(Col)  
UNION 
SELECT  
       Tbl.Col.value('@Type', 'varchar(100)'),  
       Tbl.Col.value('@Price', 'varchar(10)')
FROM   Col2.nodes('//Fruit') Tbl(Col)) Fruits FOR XML AUTO
) FROM Test2
```

Comment: This would work. My only caveat is the XML schema is quite deep. If it changes this code needs to be changed. It is a valid solution and thanks for your offer.

Comment: I think OP uses a varchar/nvarchar column store XML data. SQl Server can't store UTF-8 XML data in XML typed columns.